# If $x=t^2\sin3t$ and $y=t^2\cos3t$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

If $x=t^2\sin3t$ and $y=t^2\cos3t$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$. This is how I tried solving it:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 2t\sin3t + 3t^2\cos3t \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t\cos3t - 3t^2\sin3t \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2t\cos3t - 3t^2\sin3t}{2t\sin3t + 3t^2\cos3t} 
$$

But the answer listed is:

$$
\frac{2-3t\tan3t}{2\tan3t+3t}
$$

Is my answer incorrect, or can I simplify it even more?

Comment: Your answer is correct: simply simplify :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right trace. Just divide $t\cos 3t$ in the numerator and denominator of  $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer and the given answer are the same: just divide the numerator and denominator of your answer by $t\cos 3t$ to find the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, $\frac{2t\cos3t - 3t^2\sin3t}{2t\sin3t + 3t^2\cos3t}=\frac{t\cos{3t}}{t\cos{3t}}\frac{2-3t\frac{\sin{3t}}{\cos{3t}}}{2\frac{\sin{3t}}{\cos{3t}}+3t}=\frac{2-3t\tan3t}{2\tan3t+3t}$

Answer (score 1):

What you did is entirely correct. To show that it is equivalent to the second solution, divide numerator and denominator by $t \cos 3t$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2t\cos3t - 3t^2\sin3t}{2t\sin3t + 3t^2\cos3t}\cdot \frac{\frac 1{t\cos 3t}}{\frac{1}{t\cos 3t}} = \frac{2-3t\tan 3t}{t\tan 3t+ 3t}$$